# Postgres extended statistics with partitioning

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I am using Postgres 13 and have created a table with columns A, B and C. The table is partitioned by A with 2 possible values. Partition 1 contains 100 possible values each for B and C, whereas partition 2 has 100 completely different values for B, and 1 different value for C. I have set the statistics for both columns to maximum so that this definitely doesn't cause any issue

If I group by B and C on either partition, Postgres estimates the number of groups correctly. However if I run the query against the base table where I really want it, it estimates what I assume is no functional dependency between A, B and C, i.e. (p1B + p1C) * (p2B + p2C) for 200 * 101 as opposed to the reality of p1B * p1C + p2B * p2C for 10000 + 100.

I guess I was half expecting it to sum the underlying partitions rather than use the full count of 200 B's and 101 C's that the base table can see. Moreover, if I also add A into the group by then the estimate erroneously doubles further still, as it then thinks that this set will also be duplicated for each value of A.

This all made me think that I need an extended statistic to tell it that A influences either B or C or both. However if I set one on the base partition and analyze, the value in pg_statistic_ext_data->stxdndistinct is null. Whereas if I set it on the partitions themselves, this does appear to work, though isn't particularly useful because the estimation is already correct at this level. How do I go about having Postgres estimate against the base table correctly without having to run the query against all of the partitions and unioning them together?

Answer (score 3):

You can define extended statistics on a partitioned table, but PostgreSQL doesn't collect any data in that case. You'll have to create extended statistics on all partitions individually.

You can confirm that by querying the collected data after an `ANALYZE`:

```
SELECT s.stxrelid::regclass AS table_name,
       s.stxname AS statistics_name,
       d.stxdndistinct AS ndistinct,
       d.stxddependencies AS dependencies
FROM pg_statistic_ext AS s
   JOIN pg_statistic_ext_data AS d
      ON d.stxoid = s.oid;
```

There is certainly room for improvement here; perhaps don't allow defining extended statistics on a partitioned table in the first place.

Comment: "*perhaps don't allow defining extended statistics on a partitioned table in the first place*" - or even better: cascade it to all partitions ;) just like indexes

Answer (score 0):

I found that I just had to turn enable_partitionwise_aggregate on to get this to estimate correctly